# How can I update a database table programmatically?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a button which when pressed, sets the user's rights in the db. (If Administrator UserTypeID is set to '2' and if Customer it is set to '1'). However when I run the below code, everything remains the same. I think it's from the SQL statement but I;m not sure. Can anyone help please?

```vb
Protected Sub btnSetUser_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
    Handles btnSetUser.Click

    Dim conn As New OleDbConnection( _
      "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\...\WebSite3\db.mdb;")

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = _
      New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [User] SET [UserTypeID] WHERE Username=?", conn)

    conn.Open()
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUser.Text)

    If ddUserType.SelectedItem.Text = "Administrator" Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserTypeID", "2")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        lblSetUser.Text = txtUser.Text + "was set to Administrator."
    ElseIf ddUserType.SelectedItem.Text = "Customer" Then
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserTypeID", "1")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        lblSetUser.Text = txtUser.Text + "was set to Customer."
    End If

    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Please post a more descriptive title - something that describes the problem you are having. Simply duplicating the tags doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a parameter `@Username` your command should have such a parameter

```
SELECT [UserTypeID] FROM [User] WHERE Username = @Username
```

Also, you add an additional parameter later, which does not occur at all in your query! You call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, which works only for INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE queries.

Your query should probably look like this

```
UPDATE [User]
SET UserTypeID = @UserTypeID
WHERE Username = @Username
```

---

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand( _
  "UPDATE [User] SET UserTypeID = @UserTypeID WHERE Username = @Username", conn)

Dim userType As String = ddUserType.SelectedItem.Text
Dim userTypeId As Integer = If(userType = "Administrator", 2, 1)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserTypeID", userTypeId)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUser.Text)             
conn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
lblSetUser.Text = txtUser.Text + "was set to " & userType
```

---

UPDATE (some clarifications)

In `"UDATE [User] SET UserTypeID = @UserTypeID WHERE Username = @Username"`

`[User]`              is the name of the table

`UserTypeID`      is the name of the user type id column

`@UserTypeID`    is the name of the user type id parameter (the new value)

`Username`          is the name of the user name column

`@Username`        is the name of the user name parameter

You might have to change these names in order to match your actual situation.

Comment: It gave me an error in cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() but it was because User is a reserved keyword so I had to add [ ]. However, it gave me no errors but the UserTypeID still remains '1' even if I select 'Administrator'

Comment: I changed `Dim userTypeId As Integer = If(userType = "Administrator", 2, 1)` to `Dim userTypeId As Integer = If(userType = "Administrator", 1, 2)` and it worked. However I cannot do it the other way round, i.e. it remains '2'.

Comment: Can I put it in an If statement and the value changes depending on the dropdown box selection? For example if customer `Dim userTypeId As Integer = If(userType = "Administrator", 2, 1)` and if Administrator `Dim userTypeId As Integer = If(userType = "Administrator", 1, 2)` ?

Comment: No, this statement does this already. It does the same as `If userType = "Administrator" Then userTypeId = 2 Else userTypeId = 1 End If`. There must be something else going on here. Set a break point on this line and look if `userType` is really equal to "Administrator". The case must match! Try `userType.ToLower() = "administrator"` and if you have spaces `userType.ToLower().Trim() = "administrator"`

Answer (score 0):

You are only performing a Select Query - which will not modify any data at all.

You will want to use an Update Query, supplying parameters for both the username and the user rights number.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a `SELECT` instead of an `UPDATE`...

```
New OleDbCommand("SELECT [UserTypeID] FROM [User] WHERE Username=?", conn)
```

should be

```
New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [User] SET [UserTypeID] = @UserTypeID WHERE Username = @Username", conn)
```

Comment: I re-tried the code but it's still not updating. I used yours and then tried to modify it a bit, but all to no effect! I updated the code in the question

Comment: If should be `SET [UserTypeID] = @UserTypeID` in your code, not just `SET @UserTypeID`. The `[UserTypeID]` is the name of the table column. `@UserTypeID` is the name of the parameter.